# Additional Pricing Fee for Split Carts

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

Hello to all the geniuses out there! After days of research and trials I find I am still looking for a resolution to my pricing problems on a large wholesale site.

We sell 1000s of products that come in their own cartons/boxes of a specific quantity. We allow the user to purchase single items/split box but we would have to charge an additional 10%. This would also be relevant to any amount that is above an actual box quantity. For example a box/carton that contains say 4 items and a user buys 10 of the product, then the additional 2 should have the surcharge.

The Cart Qty is added to a custom attribute. I have tried allowing minimum order and increments but that restricts the split box option.

Open to any pointers, ideas or modules! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in a similar way which you want, You have to think in another way.

Like if you have a product A with price $10 and if any one by this in a bundle of 10 then price will be $8 per product. In that case you have to create 2 product. one for single product and another for a bundle product with qty 10.

In this case if user want to purchase 12 qty of this product they have to choice to buy 12 single product or buy 1 bundle product of qty 10 and another 2 single product, what exactly most of the ecommerce company are doing now a days.

Comment: Unfortunately we have 10000 product lines so this solution would be labour intensive.